# Autostart of Yarn process upon crash

Tags: autostart, restart, autorun

I am complete newbie to the Linux world , but had to install a server app on Ubuntu 18 ... I finally managed to get it to run , after days of hick ups .... so far so good ... but then this app has the tendency to stop  ( its still under development ).
Now here my question  to start it i go from root to /appname and then type yarn run-production . All good so far and it runs its nodejs things and tells me to go to localhost:3000 . and there will be the app ... but when it crashes i have to run the yarn command again .
Is there anyway to get this done automatically , i mean the node crashes ... start yarn run-production again ... because i can not watch the server 24 hrs :P

I know might sound all silly to you but i had a steep learning curve the last 5 days believe me :D

Thanks in advance for any help